# Print out last character of all words in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, charat

What are some clean ways to print out last characters of all words in a string. For example, a phrase like "laugh ride lol hall bozo " --> "hello" and "dog polo boo sudd noob smiley ride " --> goodbye.

These lines would return "1" and undefined. Any help is much appreciated.

```
var decrypt = function (message) {
    var solution = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        if(message.charAt(i)===" ") {
            return solution.push(message.charAt(i-1));
        };
    };
};

var resulta = decrypt("laugh ride lol hall bozo ")
console.log(resulta); // logs "hello"

var resultb = decrypt("dog polo boo sudd noob smiley ride ")
console.log(resultb); // logs "goodbye"
```

Comment: `return` exits the function.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `return` inside the loop, just append the charater to the result. When the loop is done, return what you want. Since you apparently want to return a string, you don't need an array.

```js
var decrypt = function (message) {
    var solution = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        if(message.charAt(i)===" ") {
            solution += message.charAt(i-1);
        };
    };
    return solution;
};

var resulta = decrypt("laugh ride lol hall bozo ")
console.log(resulta); // logs "hello"

var resultb = decrypt("dog polo boo sudd noob smiley ride ")
console.log(resultb); // logs "goodbye"
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks Barmar.  What is a more optimal way to print last characters in a string such that an extra " " does not have to be inserted at the end?  The insertion sort of gives the "decrypted message" away..

Comment: You can always add an extra space inside your function.

Comment: @Henry I would use `split(' ')` to split the string into words. Then loop through that, getting the last character of each. This is better than going character by character in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the words are separated by spaces you can do it in one line:

```
var decrypt = function (message) {
  return (message+" ").match(/\w\s/g).join("").replace(/\s/g,"");
}
```

The regex `/\w\s/g` will match a word character followed by a space. The `.match()` method will return an array of all such matches. `.join()` will join the array elements into a string. And then `.replace()` will remove the spaces from that string.

Note that I'm using `(message+" ")` to add an extra space to the input string just in case it doesn't already have one at the end.

Also the code I showed doesn't allow for strings that don't have any "word characters" in them. If you want to test for that you need two lines:

```
var decrypt = function (message) {
  var m = (message+" ").match(/\w\s/g);
  return m ? m.join("").replace(/\s/g,"") : "";
  //include default value for non match here^^
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. (If you don't mind hard to read code you can do the second version in one line as follows: `return ((message+" ").match(/\w\s/g)||[]).join("").replace(/\s/g,"");`)

Answer (score 0):

Another clean solution is

```
var decrypt = function (message) { 
    return message.split(' ')
        .map(function(word) { return word.slice(-1); })
        .join('');
}
```

This is relies on Array.prototype.map, which was added in ES5 with support for all modern browsers (http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.map).

Answer (score 0):

Considering you only care about the last character of each word, I would loop through the string in reverse. This allows you to also print the last character in the string without appending a space on the end of the encoded message.

```
function decrypt(message) {
    var c, secret = '', lastSpace = true;
    for (var i = (message || '').length - 1; i >= 0; i--, lastSpace = c === ' ') {
        c = message.charAt(i);
        if (lastSpace) secret = c + secret;
    }
    return secret;
}
```